# Why Observable garbage collected while Subscription still active?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, garbage-collection, observable

If I have an observable in an Angular project such as

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.observable = timer(0, 990);
    this.subscription = this.observable.subscribe((value) => console.log(value));
  }
```

And I run this very page and then switch to another page *without unsubscribing* from the observable, the garbage collection collects the observable:

[image: observable shown as deleted in chrome memory tab]

Whilst leaving the subscription untouched:
[image: subscritpion not found in chrome memory tab]

Now I'm wondering about two things:

1. How can the Observable be garbage collected whilst a subscription still has a reference to it?
2. Why is the Subscription still working if the observable is gone?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: When you make a subsription it 'remembers' the source so even when it is removed subscription is still alive.
You probably should look for 'subscription' in the inspector - it should stay

Comment: @sychd thank you for the reply! What do you mean look for it in the inspector? Which tool are you talking about? Also how can it remember the source if the source is not existant anymore? There is no reference to be had if there's no source if I understood this correctly

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice that you've checked 'subscription' in your question (I meant chrome dev tools). And about reference - I believe, it is internal mechaninsm. For example you can create some observable, for example via timer. then make a subscription, and then make `obs = null` - subscription will be alive